# Select from multiple database by filters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

My site url is looking like this:

```
http://example.com/realestate/type-apartament/rooms-3-2/key-value1-value2-value3
```

So from here I get a array like this:

```
[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => apartament
    )

[rooms] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 2
    )

[key] => Array
    (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
        [2] => value3
    )
```

My select from db should look like this:

```
Select * from properties a
LEFT JOIN properties_type b
ON a.property_type_id = b.property_type_id
WHERE b.property_type = apartament
AND a.rooms = 3 AND a.rooms = 2
```

How can I generate this select based on the key values that I have? My only solution in mind is to create a array helper with each of keys and the corresponding table, foreign key, column ...

This is my function where I process the filters from url:

```
if(!function_exists('process_filters')) {

    function process_filters($filters) {
        $data = array();
        foreach($filters as $filter):
            $filter_exploded = explode('-', $filter);
            $val = array_shift($filter_exploded);
            $data[$val] = $filter_exploded;
        endforeach;
        return $data;
    }

}
```

where $filters come from the controller method:

```
public function index(...$params)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand how far you've gotten, Do you have the array with the values? Or what? Could you show us the code of how far you've gotten / what you tried?

Comment: I edited my code, please check

Answer (score 0):

I will asume your filter already set in `$filter` variable.
then you need to call your filter model. for example i will asume your model name is `Filter_model`
then you need to call model_filter from your controller like this:

```
$this->load->model('Filter_model');
$result = $this->Filter_model->model_filter($filter); 

function model_filter($filter)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('properties');
    $this->db->join('properties_type', 'properties.property_type_id = properties_type.property_type_id', 'left');
    foreach ($filter as $key => $index) 
    {
        foreach ($index as $number => $value)
            $this->db->where($key => $value);
    }
    $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Ok but if I have 20 filters should I join all 10 tables for example? I was thinking to join only if filter is applied. And `$this->db->where($key => $value);` `$key` is not all the time same as the column name .

Comment: is all the table always has property_type_id?.